# CMake with boost( on windows) :Could not find libraries?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am trying to build my project using CMake. Iam also using boost.
The find package statement in my CMakeLists.txt file is:

find_package(Boost 1.42 REQUIRED COMPONENTS

python

system

filesystem

serialization

thread

program_options

regex

test_exec_monitor
)

The build fails and the error message i get is:
The following Boost libraries could not be found:

```
      boost_system
      boost_filesystem
      boost_serialization
      boost_thread
      boost_program_options
```

When i check my lib directories i find that the libraries are by name:
libboost< library_name >-vc100-mt.lib and not by boost_< Library_name >

Infact when i rename a single library in my lib files to fit according the boost_< LibraryName > Prefix, it doesn't complain for that library.

I see 2 solutions for the same:

1.Make changes in the CMakeLists.txt file so that it searches for libraries with correct Prefix( and suffix ).

2.Others

What could be the best one.

Comment: Your first point was the solution for me, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [FindBoost.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v2.8.10.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake)

> These last three variables are available also as environment variables:
>    Also, note they are completely UPPERCASE, except Boost_DIR.
>
> Boost_DIR or                 The preferred installation prefix for searching for
>      **BOOST_ROOT** or **BOOSTROOT**      Boost.  Set this if the module has problems finding the proper Boost installation.

Use these variables to point on folder where your boost libs installed. For example

> cmake .. -DBOOST_ROOT=C:/Boost